Is it possible to use third-party UI libraries like Material UI or Kendo UI within Apps Script for Gmail add-ons?
We are developing a Gmail add-on and are currently using the built-in Card Services UI controls. However, these controls are limited and do not offer the level of customization we need.
We are looking for a way to incorporate more advanced UI features and customization. Specifically:

Is it possible to integrate third-party UI libraries like Material UI or Kendo UI into a Gmail add-on built with Apps Script?
If so, which libraries are suitable for this purpose, and where can we find references or documentation for integrating them?
Additionally, if there are ways to extend the built-in Card Services UI controls for better customization, we would appreciate any references or examples.

Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated!

No. Currently, Google workspace addons(not editor addons) use Card service to extend user interfaces, which do not support direct html/js libraries. However, if sidebar/modal dialogs are supported by the hosting app(eg: Google sheets), then Html service can be used to support these libraries even in workspace addons1. But Gmail addon doesn't support sidebar or modal dialogs and therefore it is not currently possible to extend these  user interfaces and the customization is limited to Card service functionality.
